# return single inside FlowableTransformer

Tags: android, rx-java2

i am trying to call webservice from the flatmap, to make it code moduler i have used `FlowableTransformer` within which i am calling webservice that returns `Single`

following is the function that takes data from other flatMap and process the request , `createUpdateDevice` makes the webservice call and returns the response.

Now the problem is `syncDevices` expects to return `Publisher` and `createUpdateDevice` is returning `Single<Response>` hence i am getting complie time error

Error

> no instance of type variable r exists

```
public FlowableTransformer syncDevices(){

        return  new FlowableTransformer<RealmList<Device>,Response> () {
            @Override
            public Publisher<Response>  apply(Flowable<RealmList<Device>>  upstream) {

                return upstream.flatMap(deviceRealmList->{


                    try{

                        String userId= App.getPreference(App.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.user_id), "");
                        Request request = new Request();
                        request.setUser_id(userId);
                        request.setDevices(deviceRealmList);

                        // here i am returning 
                        return new DeviceRepo().createUpdateDevice(request).subscribe(res->{
                         // process res 

                        },err->{



                        });




                    }catch (Exception e){

                       return  Flowable.error(e);

                    }



                });
            }
        };
    }
```

code of `createUpdateDevice` function which returns the `Single<Response>`

```
public Single<Response> createUpdateDevice(Request request){

        request.setToken(App.generateToken(App.getAppContext().getString(R.string.createUpdateUserDevice)));

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        String requestJson = gson.toJson(request);

        Log.e(TAG , "DeviceRepo request "+requestJson);



        Flowable<Response> observable = new WebRequest().setBaseUrl(App.CH_BASE_URL).getRemoteClient().create(DeviceApi.class).createUpdateDevice(request);



        return  observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).firstOrError();


    }
```

Comment: Convert it back to Flowable via ... `toFlowable()`.

Comment: do you mean to say shall i use it `return new DeviceRepo().createUpdateDevice(request).toFlowable();` and then hand the emitted response in another `flatpmap`?